# No visible @interface for 'WKinterfaceGroup' declares the selector: has something changed in iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, semantics, watchkit, wkinterfacegroup

I am using **iOS SDK 8.3** and trying to follow [this tutorial](http://nilstack.github.io/2014/11/27/iWatch-App-Development-Basic-3/) to create a table in a watch kit app.

I added an Table on interface controller of the iWatch app and then linked it to my InterfaceController. The I created a custom row class and linked the row to the row controller class. I then added a couple of items in the row and linked these to outlets in the row controller class. However I get some errors:

[image]

This is my interface controller class:

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *devicesArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceGroup *devicesTable;

@end
```

And this is the code that triggers the errors:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    NSLog(@"%@ initWithContext", self);
    self.devicesArray = @[@"type A", @"type B"];
    [self.devicesTable setNumberOfRows:self.devicesArray.count withRowType:@"MyTableRowController"];

    [self.devicesTable enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        MyTableRowController* row = [self.devicesTable rowControllerAtIndex:idx];

        [row.deviceType setText: (NSString*)obj];
        [row.logo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)obj]];

    }];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial, it seems to have got a bit confused.

The `WKInterfaceGroup` that is used is for the `"MyTableRowController"` Subclass you have created.

The main `"InterfaceController"` should have devicesTable as a `WKInterfaceTable`

Apple Doc's on [WKInterfaceTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceTable)

Apple Doc's on [WKInterfaceGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceGroup_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceGroup)

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the basic question

Comment: No problem. The tutorial was slightly confusing to be fair

Answer (score 2):

Your `devicesTable` is declared as a [`WKInterfaceGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceGroup_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceGroup) which does support the methods you are calling. I am sure you meant to use [`WKInterfaceTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceTable). You likely inadvertently dragged the connection for your table from the group and not the table in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the basic question